# How to throw error if checkbox is true and date is not added in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a array of objects which has toggle value and date field, if toogle is on and date is not filled i need to throw an error message. 
But here it is taking with the last index and throws validation message based on that index value, but among the array of objects, if any of the object had boolValue as true and date is null, then i need to show popup message.

TS:

```
let dateValue = false;
    console.log(this.restrictionInfoDetails.value)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.restrictionInfoDetails.value.length; i++) {
      if (this.restrictionInfoDetails.value[i].boolValue == true) {
        if (this.restrictionInfoDetails.value[i].datetime != null) {
          dateValue = true;
        } else {
          dateValue = false;
        }
      }
    } if (this.restrictionInfoDetails.value[0].boolValue == false && this.restrictionInfoDetails.value[1].boolValue == false && this.restrictionInfoDetails.value[2].boolValue == false) {
      dateValue = true
    }
```

POPUP:

```
 if ( !dateValue) {
        this.notificationService.activate("Validation Message", errorMesage, "Ok", false).then(responseOK => {
          if (responseOK) {

          }
        });
}
```

Data:

```
this.restrictionInfoDetails.value = [
{boolValue: true, datetime: null},
 {boolValue: true, datetime: null},
{boolValue: true, datetime: null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validation over an array is always iterate over the array and break if a condition is false, or use an auxiliar variable (e.g. 'valid', and use 'valid=valid && condition')

```
let valid=true;
this.restrictionInfoDetails.value.forEach(x=>{
   valid=valid && (x.dateTime!=null || !x.boolValue)
})
console.log(valid)
```

or

```
let valid=true;
for (let value of this.restrictionInfoDetails.value){
   if (value.dateTime==null && value.boolValue)
   {
       valid=false;
       break;
   }
})
console.log(valid)
```

See that to iterate we can use `for..of` or `.forEach`, see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)

Anyway, I imagine that you ask about a custom validator for a FormArray. A customValidator in a Form array is as another customValidator, just a function (I like put in the same component)

```
myFormArray=new FormArray([],this.customValidator())

customValidator() 
   return (formArray:FormArray)=>{
    if (formArray.value)
    {
       let valid=true;
       formArray.value.forEach(x=>{
          valid=valid && (x.dateTime!=null || !x.boolValue)
       })
       return !valid?{error:'You has an error':null}
     }
}
```